# can not convert this string to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

[image]I can not convert this string to object.Why I am getting this error? please help.

```
    onSignup(data:any){
        localStorage.setItem('users',JSON.stringify(data));
        let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the value of data? When you check localStorage in the developer tools what do you see?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Try using     `function onSignup(data: any) { localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(data)); let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users') as string); }`
If you are using typescript you can't pass a string | undefined when a string is expected.